# Ajax post запрос передает null - C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, mvc

Код View

```
if (@ViewData["CountPerform"] != null)
{
<span class="form-control">Для документа - @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.doctype.description) от @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.datedoc) № @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.numberdoc) указаны следующие исполнители
</span>
}
else
{
<span class="form-control">Для документа - @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.doctype.description) от @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.datedoc) № @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.numberdoc) необходимо указать исполнителей
</span>
}

if (@ViewData["CountPerform"] != null)
{

@Html.ListBox("SETUSERID", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.USERID, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
else
{
@Html.ListBox("FULLUSERID", ViewBag.USERID as MultiSelectList, new { @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "-- укажите исполнителей --", @class = "form-control selectbox" }) 
}
if (@ViewData["CountPerform"] != null)
{
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <hr />
    <div class="right" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <input type="button" value="Закрыть" title="Закрыть форму" class="btn-close" id="_close" />
    </div>
</div>
}
else
{ 
<div style="margin-top: 150px;">
    <hr />
    <div class="right" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <input type="button" value="Сохранить" title="Сохранить" class="btn-default" id="btnSelected" role="@Model.Id" />
        <input type="button" value="Отмена" title="Закрыть форму" class="btn-close" id="close" />
    </div>
</div>      
}   



<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: false
            });

            //Добавить CheckBox в DropDownList или в ListBox
            $(document).ready(function () {
                window.asd = $('.selectbox').SumoSelect({});
            });

            var document_Id;
            $('#btnSelected').on('click', function () {
                document_Id = $(this).attr('role');
                var obj = [],
                    items = '';
                $('.selectbox option:selected').each(function (i) {
                    obj.push($(this).val());
                });
                if (obj.length > 1) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { items += obj[i] + ', ' };
                }
                else {
                    items = obj[0];
                }

                $.ajax('/Moderator/Performers',
                {
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { _userId: obj.join(), _documentId: document_Id }
                });
                alert("data: { _userId: " + obj.join() + ", _documentId: " + document_Id + " }");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Код контролера

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Performers(string _userId, string _documentId)
    {
        // _userId = "3,4,5";
        // _documentId = "4";
        // При тестовых параметрах работает Отлично
        try
        {
            var user_IdInt = _userId.Split(',').Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            foreach (var u in user_IdInt)
            {
               string sql = String.Format("insert into performers (document_Id,user_Id) values ('" + _documentId.ToString() + "','" + u.ToString() + "')");
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
            }
            TempData["msg"] = "Изменения произведены успешно";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Ошибка: " + ex.Message;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Moderator");
    }
```

код Представления не очень важен 
лучше показать 
[image: Добавить исполнителей]
как код самой функции отправки данных на сервер

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {


        //Добавить CheckBox в DropDownList или в ListBox
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.asd = $('.selectbox').SumoSelect({});
        });

        var document_Id;
        $('#btnSelected').on('click', function () {
            document_Id = $(this).attr('role');
            var obj = [];
            $('.selectbox option:selected').each(function (i) {
                obj.push($(this).val());
            });

            $.ajax('/Moderator/Performers',
            {
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { '_userId': obj.join, '_documentId': document_Id }
            });
            alert(obj + " ___ " + document_Id);

            $("#set-performer").dialog("close");
        });
    });
});
```

так вот как видно из рисунка данные считываются очень хорошо 
но во входных параметрах
public ActionResult Performers(string _userId, string _documentId)
 == NULL
см картинку
[image: Null Performers]
Подскажите что я делаю не так

p.S. Тестовая площадка (login == m, password == 10) krakoss.ru

Все работает после удаления в контроллере

```
[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

и во вьюшке

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Performers", "Moderator", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    //@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

ну и это безусловно

```
 <input type="button" value="Сохранить" title="Сохранить" class="btn-default" id="btnSelected" role="@Model.Id" />
```

а не SUBMIT

да вот какая была ошибка == [Exception: Отсутствует обязательное поле формы "__RequestVerificationToken" для защиты от подделки](http://krakoss.ru/Error_Performs.html)

Comment: Ну вот, все заработало. Молодец. Не стоит благодарности :).

Comment: "Что заработало???" - спокойствие. Ошибку с параметрами мы починили. Переходим к следующей ошибке. (Я же не виноват, что Вы не умеете писать SQL запросы :).)

Comment: Каковы типы полей `document_Id` и `user_Id` в таблице `performers`?

Comment: Смотрите добавление к ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Надо его (метод `join`) вызвать:

```
data: { _userId: obj.join(","), _documentId: document_Id }
```

А также (http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var obj = $('.selectbox').val();
```

Помните ворону из мультфильма?

> -Я наивная! Я доверчивая!

```
"... values ('" + _documentId.ToString() +
```

*Update*

Вас не настораживает появление большого красного прямоугольника с соoбщением об ошибке в верхней части страницы? И это в результате вызова `$.ajax`, который кроме посылания данных больше ничего не делает.

Поставьте `type="button"` кнопке `id="btnSelected"`. У Вас по нажатию этой кнопки происходит submit формы, которая сама по себе не содержит элементов с нужными атрибутами `name`. Поэтому параметры в методе действия контроллера - без значений.

Зачем Вам там вообще форма?

*Update*

> Оба поля имеют тип int обычный счётчик для таблицы

В таком случае уберите из SQL одинарные кавычки вокруг значений полей.

Comment: Метод join вызван = https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join. Разделить в виде == (",") указывать нет необходимости так как это значение == (",")  является значением по умолчанию. https://javascript.ru/array/join

Comment: можно так же сделать без json() Но передачи данных в контроллер НЕТ  var document_Id;
  $('#btnSelected').on('click', function () {
  document_Id = $(this).attr('role');
  var obj = [],
  items = '';
  $('.selectbox option:selected').each(function (i) {
  obj.push($(this).val());
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { items += obj[i] + ', ' };
  $.ajax('/Moderator/Performers',
  {
  async: true,
  type: 'POST',
  data: { _userId: items, _documentId: document_Id }
  });
  alert(items + " ___ " + document_Id);
   $("#set-performer").dialog("close");
  });

Comment: @ЮрийКосенко - Метод `join` **нe** вызван - в Вашем коде нет скобок после `join`. Не помещайте, пожалуйста, код в комментарии. Добавьте его в вопрос с пояснениями.

Comment: Метод join нe вызван - в Вашем коде нет скобок после join - это опечатка Предлагаю сразу перейти на сайт http://krakoss.ru/  и там всё посмотреть - сделал версию не в частичном представлении так что все видно и код страницы и какие данные подлежат передаче

Comment: type="button" кнопке id="btnSelected"  поставлен при помощи вот этого у кнопки  - role="@Model.Id" я считываю данные об Id документа которому назначаю исполнителей. а Ошибка: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. ) это как раз из контроллера == TempData["msgR-errors"] = "Ошибка: " + ex.Message;

Comment: @ЮрийКосенко Пожалуйста, не надо объяснять мне то, что и так ясно. Поставьте кнопке, по нажатию на которую посылается `$.ajax`, `type="button"`, чтобы нажатие на нее не приводило к отправке формы на сервер и перезагрузке страницы.

Comment: @ЮрийКосенко Добавьте в вопрос ту часть представления, где находится маркап для этой кнопки.